# Does this particular Kafka Streams topology introduce a race condition?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, race-condition

There are two topics involved: `commands` that is a *KStream* of - you won't believe! - commands, and `state`, which is *KTABLE* (just regular one, not a GlobalKTable).

Topology looks like that:
`commands.leftJoin(state, computeNewState).to(state)`
i.e. command acts on a current state and produces new one **to the same topic**. It's kinda `command X state -> state` in term of functional programmig; where final `state` is produced to the same place, where initial state was taken from.

It seems for me that the classical race condition is hidden there; since two (almost) simultaneous commands might produce following unfortunate sequence:

1. `command_1` arrives and consumes `state_1`;
2. after recomputation, `state_2` is produced by applying `command_1`;
3. `state_2` reactes `to` node and effectively async IO to Kafka happens...
4. ...yet it is not fast enough to be applied; meanwhile `command_2` comes with the same key such that `leftJoin` acts on the `state_1` rather then `state_2` simply because `state_2` is not yet delivered to Kafka and not yet seen by Kafka Streams instance;
5. QED.

Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is correct.

Maybe you can just use a single input topic and use an aggregation instead to modify the state? For this case, the update to the state would be synchronous.

If that is not possible, I would recommend to fall back to the Processor API. You read the state topic into a manually added state store. You also connect the state store to the processor that processes the comment topic -- this way, the processes can read **and modify** the state when processing a command directly -- writing anything back into the state input topic would be be required.